# use substring to parse out a fullname into firstname column, middle, lastname in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

Would anyone be able to help me write a query where a column is selected in a imported excel file that will parse out a fullname and divided the firstname, middle, lastname and suffix into individual columns?

Comment: what flavor of sql are you using? how are you importing the excel file to sql?

Comment: in teradata.. the file will be put into access and converted to a pipe delimiter file csv. file.

Comment: Where do you want to do the parse, Access or Teradata? What's your Teradata release? Btw, this is not a trivial task regardless of the DBMS. Even expensive address cleaning software can't do that 100% correct.

Comment: in TD. V 14.0.. Okay. I appreciate anyones assistance.

Comment: Can you share the SQL you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-invent the wheel.

TD14 has a REGEXP_SUBSTR function. I would suggest searching for a Regular Expression to split the name, there are lots of RegEx resources and you won't do better with SQL

Comment: i cant seem to get it to break up the 2nd & 3rd piece of data.. the 2nd piece is just doubleing in the 3rd column.  select firstname, lastname, mid
from (
select position(' ' in companyname)-1 pos, companyname,
 
 length(companyname)- pos rem,
 
 case when pos>0 then
 
 substring(companyname,1, pos)
 
 else companyname end as firstname,
 
 case when pos>0 then
 
 substring(companyname, pos+1, rem)
 
 else companyname end as lastname,
 
 case when pos>0 then
 
 substring(companyname, pos+1, rem)
 
 else null end as mid
 
 from customer
 where companyname is not null) x

Comment: How would i write it so where the start location is the space?

Comment: Have a look at the STRTOK function, e.g. **STRTOK(company name, ' ', 2)** It's easy to split the column in separate parts, but it's hard to define what's first/middle/last name and suffix.

Comment: Hi Dnoeth, i tried using STRTOK and it did not give me the results that i need..  Could you help with the last bit of code for the query i have above?     case when pos>0 then
 
 substring(companyname, pos+4, rem)
 
 else null end as mid

Comment: I don't know obout your logic, but with STRTOK you can easily extract the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and so in sting in your input column. Use this in your CASEs.